# Determinant of the transfer matrix

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I am interested in understanding under what conditions the transfer matrix relating the scattering amplitudes on either side of a linear network in optics/electromagnetism has a determinant of 1? Whenever I see examples of transfer matrices, they always seem to have this property but I can't seem to find it stated explicitly anywhere that it always must be.

Comment: In terms of the S-parameters the determinant is S12/S21 so I think the condition I'm looking for may be reciprocity.

Comment: you have just answered your question, it is just reciprocity.